# Simplify an XML comparison task

Tags: java, xml, csv

I'm currently working on a program which reads all elements of two xml files and compares them with each other. Afterwards it generates a csv containing the differences (this is not the problem).

I was able to read in some data and compare but I think my comparison "Algorithm" is not the most effective possible. Do you know a better solution?

What is available:

- I have an class with getter and setter for each possible tag
- I have the complete CSV generation set up
- I have the initial program code

How the code looks currently:

```
public static void CompareXMLELEMENTNAME(ArrayList<XMLELEMENTNAME> elementList1,    ArrayList<XMLELEMENTNAME> elementList2){


        ArrayList<String> strinls1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> strinls2 = new ArrayList<String>();


        ArrayList<String> notInF1 = new ArrayList<String>();    
        ArrayList<String> notInF2 = new ArrayList<String>();   

        ArrayList<XMLELEMENTNAME> ListSameonBothFile1 = new ArrayList<XMLELEMENTNAME>();
        ArrayList<XMLELEMENTNAME> ListSameonBothFile2 = new ArrayList<XMLELEMENTNAME>();

        //Create a list with the Name of each element in: elementlist1
        for(int i = 0; i < List1.size(); i++){
            XMLELEMENTNAME s1  = List1.get(i);
            strinls1.add(s1.getELEMENTNAME());

        }

        //Create a list with the Name of each element in: elementlist2
        for(int i = 0; i < List2.size(); i++){
            XMLELEMENTNAME s2  = List2.get(i);
            strinls2.add(s2.getELEMENTNAME());
        }

        //Scann the 2 files for the elements which exist in both files
        for (String a : strinls1){
            notInF2.add(strinls2.contains(a) ? a + "SAME" : a);
            if(strinls2.contains(a)){
                int i = strinls2.indexOf(a);
                ListSameonBothFile1.add(List2.get(i));
            }
        }

        for (String a : strinls2){
            notInF1.add(strinls1.contains(a) ? a + "SAME" : a);
            if(strinls1.contains(a)){
                int i = strinls1.indexOf(a);
                ListSameonBothFile2.add(List1.get(i));
            }
        }


        //Call The 
        for(int i = 0; i < ListSameonBothFile1.size(); i++){

         heavyCompareChildElement(ListSameonBothFile1.get(i),ListSameonBothFile2.get(i));
        }

        CreateCsv.generateCsvFile("unterschiede.csv");
    }


    public static void heavyCompareChildElement(UNDERELEMENT s1, UNDERELEMENT s2){

         HashMap<String, String> hashList1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
         HashMap<String, String> hashList2 = new HashMap<String, String>();

        //CREATE hashmap with all the parameters and values of the to compare ellement
        hashList1.put("TAGNAME",s1.getGETTAG());
        hashList1.put("TIME",s1.getTIME);


        //CREATE hashmap with all the parameters and values of the to compare ellement
        hashList2.put("TAGNAME",s2.getGETTAG());
        hashList2.put("TIME",s2.getTIME);



        //COMPARE and putting the found diferences in a Summary object
        for (Entry<String, String> entry: hashList1.entrySet()) {
            // Check if the current value is a key in the 2nd map
            if (!hashList2.containsValue(entry.getValue())) {


         Summary sum = new Summary();
         sum.setType("UNDERELEMENT");

            sum.setSuperName(hashList1.get("NAME"));
            sum.setName("");
            sum.setOLD(entry.getValue());
            sum.setNEW(hashList2.get(entry.getKey()));
            sum.setAttribute(entry.getKey());

            Main.addElement(sum);

            }
        }


    }
```

And this i have to do for each under element of an main xml element which is allot of code couse there are nearly +- 80 different XML objects.

The XML looks like this:

```
    <MAINELEMENT>
    <UNDERELEMENT KEY1="value" KEY2="value" KEY3="value" KEY4="value">
        <UNDEROPTIONOFUNDERELEMENT NAME="asdas" OPTIONS="sdasd" OPTIONS1="1"/>
        <ANOTHERELEMENT NAME="wefrwer" SOMEOPTIONS="fkwhjewjkh" >
            <UNDERELEMENT1 NAME="blblbl" type ="bkdk">
                <UNDERUNDERUNDERELEMENT NAME="blbalba"/>
            </ON>
            <UNDERELEMENT2 NAME="blblablbal"/>
        </ANOTHERELEMENT>
<MAINELEMENT/>
```

I would really appreciate a more efficient solution. I am aware of XMLunit but could not figure out a method.

Comment: @Rafik991 A method to compare 2 xml files by its element not carring about in which orders

Comment: But your code looks good for me, could you provide more suggestion?
This looks ok
 for (Entry<String, String> entry: hashList1.entrySet()) {
            // Check if the current value is a key in the 2nd map
            if (!hashList2.containsValue(entry.getValue())) {

Comment: @Rafik991 the code above works great but this is just for example one specific under element. i hav to copy paste this 80 times and change the whole object types and stuff for each one. so i thaught there must be an easyier way to campare 2 xml files by its elements no mather where they are located in the file if there is a element for example: TABELNAME="TEST" with unique name and it has some atributes like HORIZONTAL="TRUE" if this value is difrent in file 2 like HORIZONTAL="FALSE"  it has to write out: in ELEMENT;TABLE OLDFILE=TRUE;NEWFILE=False

Comment: Ok :-) now i ubderstood. You wan to gemeralization of your solution.

Comment: @Rafik991 yes kind of just think copy paste this 80 times and afterwards change each block so it fits is far from clean and eficient there must be a simpler les work consuming method for this ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using XMLUnit that would be as simple as that

```
public void testIdenticalAndSimilar() throws Exception {
   String controlXML = "<account><id>3A-00</id><name>acme</name></account>";
   String testXML = "<account><name>acme</name><id>3A-00</id></account>"; 
   Diff diff = new Diff(controlXML, testXML);
   assertTrue(diff.similar());
   assertFalse(diff.identical());
}
```

`similar` means ordering within tags is not relevant. `identical` is more restrictive.

This is an example from XMLUnits example code at http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/example.html. Using `DetailedDiff` you could afterwards retrieve a list of all detected differences.

Comment: Thank you so much i will try it ASAP and vote as accepted answer if it works.

Comment: thanks it works great but if i have an xml man element and it is not at the same place as the other it wil count as diference but i if on one is <account id="01"> and in the other xml is no account id 01 i dont want to check the whole element..